# Ionic Xcode Emulation deleting data

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using the following command to run my Ionic/Cordova project:

```
ionic emulate ios -l -c -s --target=iPad-Air
```

Every so often when I run this, it looks like all my local storage and data i've stored such as pouchdb data gets deleted. This makes it really hard to test things while building my app.

Is there anything I can do to make it so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` command is for live reload

to make live reload work they serve your html from a local webserver served from a local IP. When your local IP changes it will be as a new app because client storage is tied to the domain, so all the data will be lost. (If the router is restarted or some other reasons)

So, don't use `-l` option or configure your computer to use a permanent local IP address.

Comment: Haven't tested this but definitely makes sense. Thank you for the insight!